# Flutter - How to use focusNode when a Widget/Page is Loaded

Tags: flutter, hive, widget, focus, flutter-layout

I am new to Flutter and I was creating a settings page for my flutter App. On settings page I am using formbuilder. I wanted to populate the form's fields from values store in `Hive` when the focus gets on Settings page (a tab in fact). Apparently focusNode is the way to go. However all the examples that I have seen are ficus on TextFields being focused, not the Widget or Page itself.

Can anyone please guide me with a good example how to do that? For example if a Page/Widget gets loaded on mobile screen a message should be displayed.

Answer (score 1):

You need to create a statefull widget first, and the state widget has a method called initState, which is called before the build method of that widget gets called. focusNode can only be used with Input widgets

```
class SettingsScreen extends StatefulWidget {
  @override
  _SettingsScreenState createState() => _SettingsScreenState();
}

class _SettingsScreenState extends State<SettingsScreen> {

  bool _showDialog = false;
  @override
  void initState() {
    // TODO: implement initState

    // do your thing, perhaps call showDialog ?
     _showDialog=  true;
    super.initState();
  }

  @override
  Widget build(BuildContext context) {

    if(_showDialog) {
      showDilaog()
   }

    return Container(

    );
  }
}
```

Comment: This much I have already done. So effectively you are saying that I can't use FocusNode on a non-input item. So I need to look around for other options like initState.

Comment: Thanks @Ahmed Khuttab

Comment: I will give an up-vote to your answer, but I am not sure if that should be accepted as an answer, because that might be misleading to other users.